# Change rotation of tick label on subplots

Tags: matplotlib

How do you change rotation of tick label on subplot in matplotlib?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest solution is:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1)
ax.plot(range(13))
plt.xticks(rotation='vertical')
```

If you really need to use the `ax` object you can try doing something like:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1)
ax.plot(range(13))
xticks = ax.get_xticks()
ax.set_xticks(xticks)
ax.set_xticklabels(xticks, rotation='vertical')
```